# Why am I losing bytes in a loop that reads from yes?

Tags: bash

Used a loop to create users, give a default password, then expire it, but my first draft piped the password in with `yes`, which broke. This seems a standard idiom for a lot of tasks, so I'd like to better understand why it's doing this:

```
$: yes defaultString | for u in "${tst[@]}"; do head -2; done
defaultString
defaultString
faultString
defaultString
ultString
defaultString
```

The values after the first were coming in broken. What happened to my lost bytes?

The code actually used `passwd "$u" --stdin` instead of `head`:

```
yes $default | 
for u in "${tst[@]}"
do  useradd "$u"
    sudo passwd "$u" --stdin
    sudo passwd "$u" --expire
done
```

(Easy to fix - I put the value in a tempfile and read it in whole each time, but I still want to understand this a little better.)

Comment: *grumble* re: editing in a substantive change after you have an answer to the question as-initially-asked. Which vendor's implementation of `passwd`? I'd need to look at its source code.

Comment: ...or, of course, you could just `strace()` it and look at how many bytes it's reading. If it reads more than it needs to get the first line, there's your answer. (And typically the only way to read just one line's input -- unless you somehow know the length a priori -- is to do it one byte at a time and stop when you see a newline).

Comment: The same logic holds, though; you can't assume that a program reading lines of input will *only* read exactly enough bytes to find the terminating newline character, and it may or may not be possible to "put back" any extra bytes read in that process.

Comment: Apologies - realized after your answer that the question was insufficiently clear. Retrospectively I feel stupid for piping structurally sensitive data into a loop that calls a read from scratch. Exactly as you say - don't trust the read to pull bytes at a time to terminate on a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hitting a performance optimization in the consuming software (as the question was initially asked, `head`): Programs which aren't specifically and intentionally designed to consume only as much of stdin as they need (a capability which comes with a performance penalty) typically consume content as a larger block (something like 2-8kb for typical implementations of `head`), and then parse out lines as-needed.

Because `head` consumes more content than it emits, content falls between the cracks between invocations. If that's not acceptable to you, you could write an equivalent using the bash `read` builtin, which operates byte-by-byte:

```
tst=( one two three )
writeTwoLines() { IFS= read -r line1; IFS= read -r line2; printf '%s\n' "$line1" "$line2"; }
yes defaultString | for u in "${tst[@]}"; do writeTwoLines; done
```

...properly emits:

```
defaultString
defaultString
defaultString
defaultString
defaultString
defaultString
```

Comment: Thanks - I updated the original post. Would `passwd --stdin` do the same thing? Was easy to solve with `passwd "$u" --stdin < tmp` but I want to understand how the buffering would break the input. Is it just because the reads are separate calls and the buffer is breaking in the middle of a word?

Comment: Something that's been consumed by one `read()` isn't available for the next, so if `passwd` does, say, a `read(0, buf, 2048)`, that 2048 bytes is probably going to be more than just the one line intended to contain the immediately next password. It might be that there's less than the full 2kb in the buffer ready to be consumed, but assuming it's a non-blocking read, whatever *is* available up to the passed-in maximum length will be immediately consumed.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks.